# Compiler error in a fusion macro after updating BOOST

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to revive some old C++ code written by someone else, and I am having trouble getting it to compile after updating BOOST to the latest version. Below is a refactored and simplified piece of self-sufficient code that compiles with BOOST 1.42, but not with later versions. The simplified code does not make sense, but it preserves the behavior of the original with respect to this BOOST change, i.e. it compiles with v. 1.42, but with later versions it generates a compiler error shown below.

```
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/functional/invocation/invoke.hpp>  
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

#define DEFINE_STRUCT(name, fields)          \
    DEFINE_STRUCT_I(name,                    \
        BOOST_PP_CAT(DEFINE_STRUCT_X fields, 0))

#define DEFINE_STRUCT_X(x, y) ((x, y)) DEFINE_STRUCT_Y
#define DEFINE_STRUCT_Y(x, y) ((x, y)) DEFINE_STRUCT_X
#define DEFINE_STRUCT_X0
#define DEFINE_STRUCT_Y0

#define DEFINE_STRUCT_I(name, fields)        \
    class name                               \
    {                                        \
        BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I              \
            (DEFINE_STRUCT_FIELD, _, fields) \
    public:                                  \
        name() {}                            \
    public:                                  \
    template <class T, int> friend struct boost::fusion::extension::access::struct_member;\
   };                                       \
    BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT_I_PTR(name, fields)\
    struct name##_table : public table_container<name>\
    {\
    };

#define DEFINE_STRUCT_FIELD(r, _, i, xy)     \
    BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2, 0, xy)            \
        *BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2, 1, xy);

#define BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT_I_PTR(name, seq)                              \
    namespace boost { namespace fusion { namespace traits                       \
    {                                                                           \
        template <>                                                             \
        struct tag_of<name>                                                     \
        {                                                                       \
            typedef struct_tag type;                                            \
        };                                                                      \
    }}}                                                                         \
    namespace boost { namespace fusion { namespace extension                    \
    {                                                                           \
        template <>                                                             \
        struct struct_size<name> : mpl::int_<BOOST_PP_SEQ_SIZE(seq)> {};        \
        BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I(BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT_C_PTR, name, seq)     \
    }}}                                                                         \

#define BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT_C_PTR(r, name, i, xy)                         \
    template <>                                                                 \
    struct access::struct_member<name, i>                                       \
    {                                                                           \
        typedef BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2, 0, xy)* type;                            \
        static type& call(name& struct_)                                        \
        {                                                                       \
            return struct_.BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(2, 1, xy);                       \
        };                                                                      \
    };                                                                          \

template<class T>
struct table_container
{
    T val;
};



DEFINE_STRUCT(new_buildin,
(int, col1)
(char, col2))



int main()
{
    new_buildin_table b;
    boost::fusion::at<boost::mpl::int_<1>>(b.val);
    return 0;
}
```

(To compile this with BOOST 1.42, remove `access::` before `struct_member` - that was changed in a later BOOST update.)

The error message from MSVC2010 is this:

```
 1>c:\local\boost_1_56_0\boost\fusion\adapted\struct\detail\at_impl.hpp(29): error C2903: 'apply' : symbol is neither a class template nor a function template
             c:\local\boost_1_56_0\boost\fusion\sequence\intrinsic\at.hpp(65) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::fusion::extension::at_impl<boost::fusion::struct_tag>::apply<Seq,N>' being compiled
             with
             [
                 Seq=const new_buildin,
                 N=boost::mpl::int_<1>
             ]
             c:\smartdb_pqtypes_lib\smartdb_pqtypes_debug\smartdb_pqtypes_debug.cpp(78) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::fusion::result_of::at<Sequence,N>' being compiled
             with
             [
                 Sequence=const new_buildin,
                 N=boost::mpl::int_<1>
             ]
```

Any idea of what might be causing this?

Comment: I don't have access to a machine with the boost libraries built, but I notice that this code is using variadic macros and you are using msvc to compile.  I've had trouble with variadic macros in boost when using different compilers / different versions of compilers.  Check out this link: 

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/topics/variadic_macros.html

Note the last example.  It may be applicable for you.

Comment: AFAIK there are no variadic macros involved, or do you mean constructs like `DEFINE_STRUCT_X`/`DEFINE_STRUCT_Y`? They work somewhat like a variadic macro without actually using the variadic macro syntax. Anyway, if variadic macros in the user code were an issue, this would not have compiled with any BOOST version, but it does compile and work with BOOST up to v. 1.42.